# Launch Grails 3 app from IntelliJ w/ auto-reloading enabled

Tags: intellij-idea, grails-3.0

It looks like IntelliJ's  (Ultimate EAP 15) support for Grails 3 is in the early stages yet. If I do `Run -> Debug 'Grails:My App'`, I'm able to launch an app from inside IntelliJ, I can set breakpoints and it works as expected.

If I make changes however, I see in the console that the file is recompiled, but when I hit reload in the browser, I don't see the changes reflected there. I have to stop and restart the app in IntelliJ before I see them. Anyone know how I can get the auto-reloading working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After chasing this for a week, [this post](http://peedeebeesblog.blogspot.com/2015/07/grails-auto-class-reloading-broken-but.html) finally provided an explanation.

It's actually a Grails issue, not a problem with IntelliJ's Grails integration: **spaces in a file's path will break automatic reloading**. Renaming my project from `Grails Demo` to `GrailsDemo` got everything straighted out. (Storing a project in a folder like `My Documents` will also cause trouble.) The post's author indicates that this started with version 2.4.4 and it's still happening for me in 3.0.4.

Comment: This is what was causing me issues. I was pulling out my hair since the reloading was working for a college but not me, turns out I was unlucky with the way by user folder was defined (with a space). Moving the project outside of this folder did indeed fix the reloading. Thanks a bunch!